# Xstream in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde, xstream

Can anyone tell me how to use Xstream in Blackberry . In java there are tutorial available but not for blackberry. anyone has used in project. i want an example if possible plz provide the code .

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Xstream](http://x-stream.github.io/) (if this is what you are talking about) is a separate package from the BlackBerry Java API (which is based on Java ME not Java SE). It isn't available from the OS so you will either have to port it yourself, or find someone who has already done so.

Comment: Thanks for reply. i have searched a lot for example or anyone else who have done it. but couldnt get it. how to port it.  do i need to find  out source code of XStream and make changes ?

Comment: That is the essence of porting. I suspect that because the limitations of J2ME it will be a tough job. Why do you want to use xstream instead of the XML support native to the BlackBerry? BlackBerry smartphones are limited in available memory, adding unnecessary external libraries is not really the greatest idea if you can avoid it.